# How to store cell value of an Asp.Net GridView row on click in a C# variable

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am having a GridView in my page , I want that when a particular row is clicked I want the cell value of that particular row.Currently I get that that value by using something like this ,

```
protected void SearchRecordGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {


                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "location='ModifyCustomerByCategory.aspx?ApplicationNo=" + e.Row.Cells[0].Text + "'");
            }

        }
```

Currently I am passing that value as a parameter to the page , can any body tell how can I store that value in a variable or , atleast on click I assign it to a hidden field.
Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this link](http://dotnetspeaks.net/post/Selecting-GridView-Row-by-clicking-anywhere-on-the-row.aspx).
It runs through everything you will need, and on the gridview `selectedindexchanged` event you can reference the value with   `GridView.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text` or the control containing the value `Gridview.SelectedRow.FindControl("`[Control Name]`")`

Comment: thanks a lot , could you tell me what does javascript:_doPostBack do , any idea?

Comment: @freebird Well, without going too far into it, it causes the client to request a new page from the server. [Further Reading](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1082/dopostback-function/)

Comment: it helped but the selectedindexchanged event is not firing for me.

Comment: @freebird did you want to post the code or work through yourself?

Answer (score 1):

In row data bound simply save that value and use it

```
int appno =  CInt(e.Row.Cells[0].Text)
```

and if you want to use this value to next page

```
int appno = CInt(Request.Querystring("ApplicationNo"))
```

Comment: thank you , but how will I know which row was clicked with this